# Rails button_to fails with W3C validator

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, forms, w3c-validation

Outputs of a Ruby-on-Rails `button_to` have started failing in [W3C validation](https://validator.w3.org/) recently, with the returned message of:

> An input element with a type attribute whose value is hidden must not have an autocomplete attribute whose value is on or off.

So I would like to get rid of the error.

The corresponding `button_to` statement in View (ERB) in Rails-7.0.4 is

```rb
<%= button_to "Add Entry", new_article_path, form_class: "inline_form button_to",
  method: :get, params: { a_token: "abc" } %>
```

which produces an HTML (simplified!):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"> <head> <meta charset="utf-8"> <title>My Title</title> </head>
<body>
 <form class="inline_form button_to" method="get" action="/articles/new?locale=en">
  <input type="submit" value="Add Entry" />
  <input type="hidden" name="a_token" value="abc" autocomplete="off" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

If I paste this in the [W3C validator form](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options), it fails with the above-mentioned message.

Apparently, the W3C validator does not like the presence of the attribute `autocomplete` in the `input` tag with `type="hidden"`. But that is the default output of `button_to` (in Rails 7.0).

It seems the Rails team added `autocomplete=off` last year to make the HTML output *Firefox-proof* according to [Issue #42610](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42610) in [Rails repository](https://github.com/rails/rails). In the associated discussion, user jpwynn [says (2021-06-27)](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42610#issuecomment-869206338) the change would not break the W3C validation.  But seemingly it does now……

---

As far as I am aware, I have modified no relevant part in my Rails app. Yet, I notice routine testing has started to fail at W3C validations. So, I suspect W3C has changed the specification very recently (but I may be wrong!).

My Rails test is pretty simple as follows, using Gem [w3c_validators](https://rubygems.org/gems/w3c_validators/) Ver.1.3.7; it just detects any errors and fails if there is any:

```rb
 # /test/test_helper.rb
require 'w3c_validators'

def my_w3c_validate
  arerr = @validator.validate_text(response.body).errors
  assert_equal 0, arerr.size,
    "Failed in W3C-validation: ("+arerr.map(&:to_s).join(") (")+")"
end
```

with `Gemfile`:

```rb
group :development, :test do
  gem 'w3c_validators', '~> 1', '>= 1.3.6'  # => 1.3.7 in reality
end
```

So, is the output of Rails `button_to` a valid HTML?  If not, how can I modify it so that the output HTML will be a valid HTML?
I am using the most recent stable version, Rails-7.0.4.

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C HTML checker (validator) here. As far as why the checker didn’t report an error for `<input type="hidden" name="a_token" value="abc" autocomplete="off" />` previously but does now: It’s because the checker previously wasn’t checking a restriction in the spec that it should’ve been, but in https://github.com/validator/validator/pull/1458 on 2022-10-26, we landed a change to align the checker with the spec requirements, at https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute:autofill-anchor-mantle-2

Comment: The actual spec requirement is _“When wearing the autofill anchor mantle, the `autocomplete` attribute, if specified, must have a value that is an ordered set of space-separated tokens consisting of just autofill detail tokens (i.e. the "on" and "off" keywords are not allowed)”_ — where _“wearing the autofill anchor mantle”_ just means that the `input` element has a `type=hidden` attribute.

Comment: @sideshowbarker Crystal clear. Thank you!! So, W3C HTML checker is doing definitely right, whereas the behaviour of Rails (in order to deal with Firefox's bugs?) violates the spec of the `<input>` tag.

Comment: Yeah the checker is right and it just following the spec requirements. I can’t speak to what Rails might be doing, but in general, any output that includes `autocomplete="off"` on an `input` element with `type="hidden"` would not conform to the requirements in the spec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maintainer of W3C HTML checker (validator) @sideshowbarker kindly gave information (see comments in the question).

Here is a summary:

1. W3C HTML checker is doing definitely right:
   `<input type="hidden" name="abc" autocomplete="off">` is invalid.

   - According to the [HTML Form specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofilling-form-controls:-the-autocomplete-attribute:autofill-anchor-mantle-2),

     > When wearing the autofill anchor mantle, the autocomplete attribute, if specified, must have a value that is an ordered set of space-separated tokens consisting of just autofill detail tokens (i.e. the "on" and "off" keywords are not allowed)” — where “wearing the autofill anchor mantle

     which is basically applied to the `<input type=hidden>` tag.
2. The new check item was very recently (2022-10-26) implemented on the checker, hence the recent change in the result of my Rails W3C tests. See [Git pull request](https://github.com/validator/validator/pull/1458)
3. The HTML generated by Rails' `button_to` method violates the spec of the `<input>` tag.

   - Ironically, the HTML generation by `button_to` changed recently (last year) to deal with Firefox's mal-behaviour; it did pass the W3C HTML validation at that time! See Rails [Github Issue #42610](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/42610)

Now, since the W3C validator is doing right, you have two options:

1. Change the way of HTML generation by Rails' `button_to`
2. Modify the result of W3C validations in this respect so that the validation would not fail just because of this error and you can still use all the other validations.

Here is the measure in the second policy.  You pass the Array of `W3CValidators::Message` and this method returns the same Array but with the said-errors removed.  The original relevant error message can be recorded in `Logger`.  I put the script (but with more extensive description) in [Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/masasakano/57d40a1a8a630a9ca78ac22fae375161), too.

```rb
# @example Usage, maybe in /test/test_helper.rb
#   # Make sure to write in /config/environments/test.rb
#   #    config.ignore_w3c_validate_hidden_autocomplete = true
#   #
#   #require 'w3c_validators'
#   errors = @validator.validate_text(response.body).errors
#   errors = _may_ignore_autocomplete_errors_for_hidden(errors, "W3C validaiton failed: ")
#   assert_empty errors, "Failed in W3C validation: "+errors.map(&:to_s).inspect
#
# @param errs [Array<W3CValidators::Message>] Output of +@validator.validate_text(response.body).errors+
# @param prefix [String] Prefix of the warning message recorded with Logger.
#    If empty, no message is recorded in Logger.
# @return [Array<String>]
def may_ignore_autocomplete_errors_for_hidden(errs, prefix="")
  removeds = []
  return errs if !Rails.configuration.ignore_w3c_validate_hidden_autocomplete
  errs.map{ |es|
    # Example of an Error:
    #   ERROR; line 165: An “input” element with a “type” attribute whose value is “hidden” must not have an “autocomplete” attribute whose value is “on” or “off”
    if /\AERROR\b.+\binput\b[^a-z]+\belement.+\btype\b.+\bhidden\b.+\bautocomplete\b[^a-z]+\battribute\b/i =~ es.to_s
      removeds << es
      nil
    else
      es
    end
  }.compact

ensure
  # Records it in Logger
  if !removeds.empty? && !prefix.blank?
    Rails.logger.warn(prefix + removeds.map(&:to_s).uniq.inspect)
  end
end
```